# Pass Json data using Jquery Ajax then display response

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Why is this not working? Jquery will take the value on change and send it using ajax in json format to a php file. then same jquery will take response and append it. $(#orderSummary) never display success for me to verify that it actually get a response.

```
         $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#prodcat").change(function(){
    var prodid = $(this).val();

        $("#orderSummary").append(prodid);

    $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'getproduct.php',
     data: {'prodcat':prodid},
     dataType: 'json',
     success:function(response){

        $("#orderSummary").append(success);

      var len = response.length;

      $("#product").empty();

      for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
       var name = response[i]['name'];
       var detail = response[i]['detail'];
       var price = response[i]['price'];

       $("#product").append("<option value='"+name+"'>"+name+"</option>")
      }
     }
    });
   });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending wrong varaible

change

```
 $("#orderSummary").append(success);
```

to

```
 $("#orderSummary").append(response);
```

OR if you want to append `success` message to `orderSummary` then append it with `''`

```
$("#orderSummary").append('success');
```

Comment: Oh thanks. I don't think it ever got a response because it is still empty. PHP is in another file. echo json_encode($result_arr);   Maybe it does not echo the array back to the ajax request.